# Jackson JSON: Implementing a TypeIdResolver

Tags: java, types, jackson, resolver

I'm currently working on designing base API to use static data in my application server and I choose Jackson as a way to serialize my data. The problem is that I don't want any nesting in the final JSON file so I end up with this :

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class Parent {
    public long id;
    public String name;

    @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
    @JsonManagedReference
    public Set<Child> children = new HashSet<>();
}

@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class Child {
    public long id;
    public String name;

    @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
    @JsonBackReference
    public Parent parent;
}

public static class Registry {
    public Set<Parent> parents = new HashSet<>();
    public Set<Child> children = new HashSet<>();
}
```

This works great for serializing, I get something like :

```
{
    "parents" : [ {
        "id" : 1,
        "name" : "DADDY",
        "children" : [ 1, 2 ]
    } ],
    "children" : [ {
        "id" : 1,
        "name" : "JUNIOR"
    }, {
        "id" : 2,
        "name" : "JUNIOR'S SISTER"
    } ]
}
```

But now, I want to deserialize it but then unfortunately an exception is thrown : `Could not resolve Object Id [2] (for [simple type, class org.photon.Main$Child])`. After some research, I was told that I have to implement a custom type id resolver but I could not do anything because of the lack of resource. I would like to tell Jackson how to get the instances of Parent to children and instances of Child to parents when deserializing Registry.

Do you know how I can fix that or is there any other way to do it ?

Comment: What limitation is having a nested JSON file causing you?  I'm not strictly familiar with the way Jackson deserializes classes, but my guess is that it doesn't know how to resolve the children collection back into the object graph without a custom resolver implementation.

Comment: I guessed that too but I don't know how to correctly implement a custom type id resolver because of the lack of resource so I am asking some Jackson "expert" how I could.